# Is High Maturity and Proficiency in Calculus and Linear algebra necessary for successful research?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

Is it the case that most successful mathematicians have very high Maturity and Proficiency(do it without thinking) in ***Calculus and Linear algebra***, both **calculation** part(double/line integrals, eigenvalues etc...) and **theory** part (reconstruction of important theorems with proofs without referring to books) ?

In other words, is these ***maturities and proficiency*** very important for doing further research ?

If not, are there well-known mathematicians in the history who somehow not very proficiently perform the elementary calculus and linear algebra etc.. both in calculation and theorems

(e.g. multiple/line integrals, tangent plane, eigenvalues, quadratic forms,  solve ODE....)

but still very successful in research ?

Comment: I would say *no*, but that experience probably helps you develops muscles that are useful everywhere else. For me, I felt like real analysis and topology acted like steroids that really gave me a boost (even though I only consider myself an algebraist.) You can probably get a similar maturity by delving into many other disciplines, say geometry or topology.

Comment: And arguing in the other direction *yes* because through calculus and linear algebra you learn an awful lot about the real numbers, functions and the ordinary Euclidean metric. These are certainly very useful for everything else. However, I don't think triple integrals or intensive vector analysis are necessarily as fundamental as the real numbers...

Comment: I'd say it is mostly a consequence of expertise rather than the other way around. After a certain time you just have the feeling for how things work and you're able to reconstruct it, most of it at least.